# Same code but different results from different platform

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, glfw, glut

I have an exercise to draw a simple cube that teacher asks me to fill in where: 
 **"YOUR CODE HERE ..."**. 
I have done it but when coming to see the result, it rendered something weird ([Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi4Zc.png) ). I have run that code on my friend's laptop and it gave a really good cube ([Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vINgM.png)). 
There are **3 files** in used:

- **cube.py**:

```
from libs.buffer import *
import glfw


class Cube(object):
    def __init__(self, vert_shader, frag_shader):
        self.vertices = np.array([
            # YOUR CODE HERE to specify vertices' coordinates
            [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5],  # A 0
            [0.5, -0.5, -0.5],  # B 1
            [0.5, -0.5, 0.5],  # C 2
            [-0.5, -0.5, 0.5],  # D 3
            [-0.5, 0.5, -0.5],  # E 4
            [0.5, 0.5, -0.5],  # F 5
            [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],  # G 6
            [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5]  # H 7
        ], dtype=np.float32)

        self.indices = np.array([
            # YOUR CODE HERE to specify indices
            4, 7, 5, 6,  # Top
            6, 0,
            0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 0, 4,  # Sides
            5, 1,
            0, 3, 1, 2  # Bottom
        ])

        # YOUR CODE HERE to compute vertices' normals using the coordinates
        normals = np.random.normal(0, 1, (self.vertices.shape[0], 3)).astype(np.float32)
        normals[:, 2] = np.abs(normals[:, 2])
        self.normals = normals / np.linalg.norm(normals, axis=1, keepdims=True)

        # colors: RGB format
        self.colors = np.array([
            # YOUR CODE HERE to specify vertices' color
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],  # black
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],  # red
            [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],  # yellow
            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],  # green
            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],  # blue
            [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],  # magenta
            [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],  # white
            [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]  # cyan
        ], dtype=np.float32)

        self.vao = VAO()

        self.shader = Shader(vert_shader, frag_shader)
        self.uma = UManager(self.shader)
        #

    """
    Create object -> call setup -> call draw
    """

    def setup(self):
        # setup VAO for drawing cylinder's side
        self.vao.add_vbo(0, self.vertices, ncomponents=3, stride=0, offset=None)
        self.vao.add_vbo(1, self.colors, ncomponents=3, stride=0, offset=None)

        # setup EBO for drawing cylinder's side, bottom and top
        self.vao.add_ebo(self.indices)

        return self

    def draw(self, projection, view, model):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        modelview = view

        self.uma.upload_uniform_matrix4fv(projection, 'projection', True)
        self.uma.upload_uniform_matrix4fv(modelview, 'modelview', True)

        self.vao.activate()
        GL.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, self.indices.shape[0], GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

    def key_handler(self, key):
        if key == glfw.KEY_1:
            self.selected_texture = 1
        if key == glfw.KEY_2:
            self.selected_texture = 2
```

- **libs/buffer.py**:

```
import OpenGL.GL as GL
import cv2


class VAO(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vao = GL.glGenVertexArrays(1)
        GL.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        GL.glBindVertexArray(0)
        self.vbo = {}
        self.ebo = None

    def add_vbo(self, location, data, ncomponents=3, dtype=GL.GL_FLOAT, normalized=False, stride=0, offset=None):
        self.activate()
        buffer_idx = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_idx)
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        # location = GL.glGetAttribLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(location, ncomponents, dtype, normalized, stride, offset)
        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(location)
        self.vbo[location] = buffer_idx
        self.deactivate()

    def add_ebo(self, indices):
        self.activate()
        self.ebo = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ebo)
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        self.deactivate()

    def __del__(self):
        GL.glDeleteVertexArrays(1, [self.vao])
        GL.glDeleteBuffers(1, list(self.vbo.values()))
        if self.ebo is not None:
            GL.glDeleteBuffers(1, [self.ebo])

    def activate(self):
        GL.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)  # activated

    def deactivate(self):
        GL.glBindVertexArray(0)  # activated


class UManager(object):
    def __init__(self, shader):
        self.shader = shader
        self.textures = {}

    @staticmethod
    def load_texture(filename):
        texture = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename, 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return texture

    def _get_texture_loc(self):
        if not bool(self.textures):
            return 0
        else:
            locs = list(self.textures.keys())
            locs.sort(reverse=True)
            ret_id = locs[0] + 1
            return ret_id

    """
    * first call to setup_texture: activate GL.GL_TEXTURE0
        > use GL.glUniform1i to associate the activated texture to the texture in shading program (see fragment shader)
    * second call to setup_texture: activate GL.GL_TEXTURE1
        > use GL.glUniform1i to associate the activated texture to the texture in shading program (see fragment shader)
    * second call to setup_texture: activate GL.GL_TEXTURE2
        > use GL.glUniform1i to associate the activated texture to the texture in shading program (see fragment shader)
    and so on
    
    """

    def setup_texture(self, sampler_name, image_file):
        rgb_image = UManager.load_texture(image_file)

        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)  # must call before calling to GL.glUniform1i
        texture_idx = GL.glGenTextures(1)
        binding_loc = self._get_texture_loc()
        self.textures[binding_loc] = {}
        self.textures[binding_loc]["id"] = texture_idx
        self.textures[binding_loc]["name"] = sampler_name

        GL.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0 + binding_loc)  # activate texture GL.GL_TEXTURE0, GL.GL_TEXTURE1, ...
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_idx)
        GL.glUniform1i(GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, sampler_name), binding_loc)

        GL.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGB,
                        rgb_image.shape[1], rgb_image.shape[0], 0, GL.GL_RGB, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgb_image)
        GL.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR)
        GL.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR)

    def upload_uniform_matrix4fv(self, matrix, name, transpose=True):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, transpose, matrix)

    def upload_uniform_matrix3fv(self, matrix, name, transpose=False):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glUniformMatrix3fv(location, 1, transpose, matrix)

    def upload_uniform_vector4fv(self, vector, name):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glUniform4fv(location, 1, vector)

    def upload_uniform_vector3fv(self, vector, name):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glUniform3fv(location, 1, vector)

    def upload_uniform_scalar1f(self, scalar, name):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glUniform1f(location, scalar)

    def upload_uniform_scalar1i(self, scalar, name):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.shader.render_idx)
        location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.render_idx, name)
        GL.glUniform1i(location, scalar)
```

- **viewer.py** (file to run):

```
import OpenGL.GL as GL              # standard Python OpenGL wrapper
import glfw                         # lean windows system wrapper for OpenGL
import numpy as np                  # all matrix manipulations & OpenGL args
from itertools import cycle   # cyclic iterator to easily toggle polygon rendering modes
from libs.transform import Trackball
from cube import *
# ------------  Viewer class & windows management ------------------------------
class Viewer:
    """ GLFW viewer windows, with classic initialization & graphics loop """
    def __init__(self, width=800, height=800):
        self.fill_modes = cycle([GL.GL_LINE, GL.GL_POINT, GL.GL_FILL])
        
        # version hints: create GL windows with >= OpenGL 3.3 and core profile
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL.GL_TRUE)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.RESIZABLE, False)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.DEPTH_BITS, 16)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.DOUBLEBUFFER, True)
        self.win = glfw.create_window(width, height, 'Viewer', None, None)

        # make win's OpenGL context current; no OpenGL calls can happen before
        glfw.make_context_current(self.win)

        # initialize trackball
        self.trackball = Trackball()
        self.mouse = (0, 0)

        # register event handlers
        glfw.set_key_callback(self.win, self.on_key)
        glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(self.win, self.on_mouse_move)
        glfw.set_scroll_callback(self.win, self.on_scroll)

        # useful message to check OpenGL renderer characteristics
        print('OpenGL', GL.glGetString(GL.GL_VERSION).decode() + ', GLSL',
              GL.glGetString(GL.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION).decode() +
              ', Renderer', GL.glGetString(GL.GL_RENDERER).decode())

        # initialize GL by setting viewport and default render characteristics
        GL.glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1)
        #GL.glEnable(GL.GL_CULL_FACE)   # enable backface culling (Exercise 1)
        #GL.glFrontFace(GL.GL_CCW) # GL_CCW: default

        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST)  # enable depth test (Exercise 1)
        GL.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LESS)   # GL_LESS: default


        # initially empty list of object to draw
        self.drawables = []

    def run(self):
        """ Main render loop for this OpenGL windows """
        while not glfw.window_should_close(self.win):
            # clear draw buffer
            GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            win_size = glfw.get_window_size(self.win)
            view = self.trackball.view_matrix()
            projection = self.trackball.projection_matrix(win_size)

            # draw our scene objects
            for drawable in self.drawables:
                drawable.draw(projection, view, None)

            # flush render commands, and swap draw buffers
            glfw.swap_buffers(self.win)

            # Poll for and process events
            glfw.poll_events()

    def add(self, *drawables):
        """ add objects to draw in this windows """
        self.drawables.extend(drawables)

    def on_key(self, _win, key, _scancode, action, _mods):
        """ 'Q' or 'Escape' quits """
        if action == glfw.PRESS or action == glfw.REPEAT:
            if key == glfw.KEY_ESCAPE or key == glfw.KEY_Q:
                glfw.set_window_should_close(self.win, True)

            if key == glfw.KEY_W:
                GL.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, next(self.fill_modes))

            for drawable in self.drawables:
                if hasattr(drawable, 'key_handler'):
                    drawable.key_handler(key)

    def on_mouse_move(self, win, xpos, ypos):
        """ Rotate on left-click & drag, pan on right-click & drag """
        old = self.mouse
        self.mouse = (xpos, glfw.get_window_size(win)[1] - ypos)
        if glfw.get_mouse_button(win, glfw.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT):
            self.trackball.drag(old, self.mouse, glfw.get_window_size(win))
        if glfw.get_mouse_button(win, glfw.MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT):
            self.trackball.pan(old, self.mouse)

    def on_scroll(self, win, _deltax, deltay):
        """ Scroll controls the camera distance to trackball center """
        self.trackball.zoom(deltay, glfw.get_window_size(win)[1])



# -------------- main program and scene setup --------------------------------
def main():

    """ create windows, add shaders & scene objects, then run rendering loop """
    viewer = Viewer()
    # place instances of our basic objects

    model = Cube("./gouraud.vert", "./gouraud.frag").setup()
    viewer.add(model)

    # start rendering loop
    viewer.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    glfw.init()                # initialize windows system glfw
    main()                     # main function keeps variables locally scoped
    glfw.terminate()           # destroy all glfw windows and GL contexts
```

Hope someone can help me solve this conflict. 
P/s: I use MacOS whereas my friend uses Window.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you came to the conclusion that you need those 22 indices? I know of a triangle strip algorithm for a cube, but that only requires 14 indices = 12 faces.

Comment: In this case, I use Index Buffer Objects (the teacher asks us to do). For more details, you can have a glance at [this blog](https://www.learnopengles.com/tag/triangle-strips/?fbclid=IwAR1jgaaX-dWhbbElOetOAmpKE-wg3PjBztGPZsG50D5t1P0xdt7aCEWW1Z4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the data type of index array in **cube.py**. We need to specify a specific type in order to run smoothly through various OSs. 
For example: `self.indices = np.array([...], dtype=np.uint32)`.